# C - Sum and finding largest/smallest

Tags: c, sum

Could someone take a look at my code and give me some pointers why it isn't working properly. It is supposed to ask for numbers as long as they're positive integers and then calculate sum of them, divide it by largest and multiply it by smallest number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

 int n, largest=0, smallest=0;
 float sum=0;
 scanf("%d", &n);
 while (n > 0) {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n > largest) {
    largest = n;
    }
    if (n < smallest) {
    smallest = n;
    }
    sum += n;
 }
 sum = sum / largest * smallest;
 printf("%f\n", sum);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Elaborate on it not working correctly.

Comment: I put scanf on bottom of loop but obvious problem was with smallest, i put in a temporary fix saying it's original value is 100, but that won't work for numbers above 100, right?

Comment: @user2627736: That's what `INT_MAX` is for - see my answer.

Comment: `sum = sum / largest * smallest;` -- what is that supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

Because `smallest` starts at zero, it will never change because `if (n < smallest)` will never be true.  You need:

```
 int smallest = INT_MAX;
```

or similar.  For `INT_MAX` you'll need:

```
#include <limits.h>
```

at the top.

Comment: This is required but not sufficient... `scanf` has to move at the end of while loop or else -ve numbers can be given as input (after the 1st input) and they will be added to sum and also set as minimum... which will make the code incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

Move scanf to end of while or else your first input is missed and secondly, you can accept a negative input and do all the processing on it.
Also, smallest has to be the Max value otherwise with `smallest = 0`, `n < smallest` will not work

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

 int n, largest=0, smallest=INT_MAX;
 float sum=0;
 scanf("%d", &n);
 while (n > 0) {
    if (n > largest) {
    largest = n;
    }
    if (n < smallest) {
    smallest = n;
    }
    sum += n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
 }
 sum = sum / largest * smallest;
 printf("%f\n", sum);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `while` loop condition from `while (n > 0)` to `while (scanf("%d", &n) && n > 0)`. In this case you can also remove the first `scanf("%d", &n)` and the one in the body of the `while` loop.

You problem is that because your `scanf("%d", &n)` is in the **body** of your while loop,  it is not checked for being greater then `0` when performing `if (n > largest)` and `if (n < smallest)`.

Also you should initialize your `smallest` to the max possible value. In this case being `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails primarily due to `int smallest=0`.  This can be solve a number of ways.  I recommend setting the first value read to `largest` and `smallest`.  Also your 2nd `scanf("%d", &n);` s/b at the end of the loop.

You have additional problems, though subtle.

1. Summing `int` into a `float` can lose precision in many environments when `int` values > about 24,000,000.  Suggest a large integer type to sum your values like uint64_t.
2. The final "divide it by largest and multiply it by smallest number" it the only place floating point math is needed.   The math you did was OK but more likely subject to rounding errors.
3. If your first `n` <= 0, you will perform a divide by 0.

Sample fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n, largest = 1, smallest = 0; // set largest to 1 to deal with first n being < 0 and thus avoiding /0
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  while (n > 0) {
    if (sum > 0) {
      if (n > largest) {
        largest = n;
      }
      if (n < smallest) {
        smallest = n;
      }
    } else { // This is the first time as sum is 0
      largest = smallest = n;
    }
    sum += n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
  }
  printf("%lf\n", ((double) sum) / smallest * largest);
  return 0;
}
```